# Saving temporary file name after uploading file with uplodify

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, uploadify

I have this script

```
<?php

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . $_POST['folder'] . '/';
  $pathinfoFile = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
  $targetFile =  str_replace('//', '/', $targetPath) . uniqid() . '.' . $pathinfoFile['extension'];
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile); 
}
```

This script is from [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com), modified for saving the file with unique name. I need to save the temporary, unique and original names after the user has uploaded the file. These values will be used when the user finally submits the form. I have tried to save these values in `$_SESSION` but I'm having the problem outlined here:

http://uploadify.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=43 ,

I tried  the solution from forum but it did not work, is there an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you implemented the solution outlined in the uploadify forum link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry i tried one more time with `$_POST['PHPSESSID']` and is working right now , thanks for help